# Which class Responsible for setting Tax

Tags: magento2, tax

Inside the Order View page.  below the Items Ordered section **Order Total** section in which subtotal ,shipping ,discount,Tax,Grand Total etc ... i found the class where these thing are come But Tax is not comming from the same class where Sub Total etc comming . . . 
Any One can Guid me where the **Tax** **amount** comming which class is responsible ? I want to make some customization on Tax.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Class Responsible For rendering Tax?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263869/which-class-responsible-for-rendering-tax)

Comment: You can modify tax calculation using observer

Comment: You can review example here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/138741/21339

Comment: i don't change Tax Calulation . I just need Class name which responsible for setting Tax in frint end at Total Section in order view page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tax below class

```
Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation
```

Thanks

Comment: i don't change calculation method of magento2 . i want to know which class responsible for displaying Tax on front end in Order Total section .

Comment: In admin order view Tax is showing from below file                         
vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\totals\tax.phtml